# Nextjs Sitemap not fetch by Google search console

Tags: google-search-console, search-engine-indexing, javascript, sitemap, next.js

I created a small web application with Next.js and it works fine. Now I need to index that on google. It has dynamic pages too. So I created a dynamic sitemap using [Sitemap](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sitemap) npm module. But when I tried to add it to the search console it displays an error saying that the **sitemap couldn't read**. After that, I validated it using this [website](https://www.xml-sitemaps.com/validate-xml-sitemap.html) and it says my sitemap has no issues. What should I do to get rid of this error? I have added a photo of my error below.

Thanks[image]

Comment: Is there something that is blocking Googlebot from accessing the sitemap.xml? Did you find anything in server logs (corresponding to the user-agent that contains Googlebot)?

Comment: I didn't find such a thing as that. But I have hosted this on vercel with their free subdomain. So is that be the problem?

Comment: Maybe. You may have to check with Vercel support on this.

Comment: An XML sitemap is not going to get your site indexed.   It is a common misconception, see my blog: [Myth: An XML sitemap is needed for SEO; it helps rankings](https://blog.ostermiller.org/xml-sitemap-rankings/)  You need to create links to your dynamic pages if you want to get them indexed.  It doesn't matter whether Google is processing the sitemap or not.

Answer (score 2):

A way to test and find the source of the problem is to generate another sitemap and introduce it to Google Search Console. If that new one submitted successfully, you can conclude the first one really had some sort of issues.
I suggest to use **Yoast SEO plugin** to generate a new one because of it's easily usage. Hope to be helpful.

Comment: I tried adding sitemaps in a couple of different ways. But none of them are worked. I think the Yoast SEO plugin is for WordPress. Since this is a NEXT.JS project are there any possibilities to use that on NEXT.JS?

Comment: @PasinduPrabhashitha You're right. It's for WP. I suggest using this link to repair it.
https://cheatcode.co/tutorials/how-to-generate-a-dynamic-sitemap-with-next-js